# How can I search the internet via unity dash?

Tags: unity, internet, unity-dash, google

I would like the option to be able to search the internet in directly in unity. Much like the calculator package works, just adding numbers in and having it compute, I would like to be able to type in a word or phrase, and have an option to search Google for it.

Sorry if this has already been asked, but I can find nothing other than "Web Sources" but it really is not what I am looking for. Is this already an idea for a lens?

Comment: Well, while you currently (to my knowledge) can't surf through the unity dash, you can go to webpages through the dash. Type a web address and it'll give you an option to browse the page. Here's to hoping for a lens soon!

Answer (score 3):

Install the **DuckDuckGo Unity Lens** !
I think it is perfectly what you are searching for. You will get three scopes: Results, Related Searches and Related Topics.

To install it, type the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:w-vollprecht/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install duckduckgo-lens
```

More details on http://www.iloveubuntu.net/unity-duckduckgo-lens-released-ppa-available

Answer (score -1):

*'starting from first principles ..' - Marcus Aurelius*

**What do you need?**

Starting with a small Firefox browser window, already open, with the 'search box' at top right.  You need somewhere to type the search query (and/or select which provider) and somewhere to see the results.  This describes a browser.

**Are your needs somehow different?**

Comment: Alright, I am getting the ppa now, and will download the lens. I think that is going to be the solution to my problem. Thanks again!